# r aggregate value by country and department

Tags: r, aggregation

I have a large dataset with 200 countries, departments and costs.

70 000 rows - (countries and departments are more than 1 time in dataset)

My target is to get a data frame looking the following:

[target output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjdfr.jpg)

Comment: please provide input and expected output in text, helps to copy paste

Comment: To expand on @VivekKalyanarangan point a little please read [How do I ask a good question? - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a data frame called `df`...

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(country, department) %>%
  summarise(costs = sum(costs)) %>%
  spread(department, costs)
```

Read more about [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/), [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/) and the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/), they will make your life a *lot* easier.

Comment: THANKS! That is exactly what I was looking for.